# Taste of Haskell : definition of . (composition)

Tags: haskell

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLj1QV11o9g) talk at 52:40 this slide below is discussed.

I don't quite understand this definition.

Why is the `x` needed in the definition ?

Why is the output not needed ?

For example why is the definition not `(f . g) x -> y = f (g x) -> y` or something like that ?

Is it easier to understand this definition if I look at it as a **rewriting rule** ? Whenever the expression evaluator encounters a pattern like on the left side it should rewrite it to the right side?

Is the rewriting rule interpretation the only correct way to understand this definition ? (This interpretation is the only way that this definition makes sense to **me** but I am not even sure if this is the correct way to interpret this definition.) I have to admit that I am quite a beginner in Haskell.

EDIT:

Or this definition is just a sugar for a lambda expression ?

Or the lambda expression is sugar for the rewriting rule ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about `x` being needed in the definition but not the output. `x` is in the definition as a placeholder for the input, and the output is `f (g x)`, which in an imperative language or math would be `f(g(x))`, i.e. straightforward function composition.

Comment: I think you're confusing the type signature (the line with "->") and the definition (the line with "=")

Comment: I am wondering whether all definitions are just rewriting rules ? I am not sure if it is OK to interpret this definition also as a rewriting rule.

Comment: @Jhegedus you could see them as rewriting rules. The original lambda calculus defines evaluation of lambda expressions through a series of reductions, which in essence are rules for rewriting the expression

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "rewriting rule". In a functional language, same input = same output, so you can express everything as a lookup table. But it's much more sensible to do (e.g.) floating-point math.

Comment: equations in Haskell define lambda expression but because of referential transparency they behave like rewrite rules. `f a b c = ...` defines `f` as `(\a b c-> ...)` but can be reasoned about in equational manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Composition can be written in several equivalent ways.

```
(.) = \f g -> \x -> f (g x)
(.) = \f g x -> f (g x)
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

The last example says "a composition of two functions gives a function, such that..."

More equivalent expressions:

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
(.) f g x = f (g x)
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Comment: These are completely equivalent ? The evaluator (when it does the rewriting/reduction) does always the same thing no matter which way I write the definition ? All definitions give the same number of reduction steps?

Comment: @jhegedus yes, they all desugar to the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't `f . g x` need to be `(f . g) x`?

Comment: @TomEllis yes, sorry.

Comment: To be clear, they mean the same thing denotationally, but GHC specifically might compile them differently. It's allowed to do that as long as it doesn't change the value.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the infix notation is confusing you? Let's look at another way to write that definition:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)     -- definition 1
```

So we can think of `(.)` as a function which takes three parameters, `f` (a function), `g` (another function), and `x` (a value). It then returns `f ( g x)`. To invoke this function, we could write an expression like:

```
(.) head tail "test"
```

which would return `'e'`. However, functions with names beginning with certain special characters (like `.`) can be used *infix* style, like so:

```
(head . tail) "test"
```

Now, another way to define `.` is like this:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)       -- definition 2
```

This is identical to "definition 1", but the notation may look a little strange, with the function "name" `.` appearing after the first parameter! But this is just another example of infix notation.

Now, let's look at how this function is actually defined in `Prelude`:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

This is equivalent to definitions 1 and 2, but uses a syntax you may not be familiar with, *lambda notation*. The right hand side introduces an unnamed function with a single parameter `x`, and defines that function to be `f (g x)`. So the whole thing says that that the function `(.) f g` is defined to be that unnamed function! You may wonder why anyone would write this in such a strange way. It will make more sense when you've worked with infix notation and lambdas for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was not the infix notation. The confusion was that I did not make the proper connection between this definition and the reduction rules (explained in the talk earlier).

Answer (score 2):

`->` is needed for the type definition of the function, i.e to say what types the functions take as arguments and what type has his result. Explanations:

- `f :: ...` is something like "function `f` has type `...`
- `(a -> b)` means the type "a function which takes an argument of type `a` and returns an argument of type `b`"
- `(a -> b) -> (b->c) -> (a->c)` means "a function which takes a function of type `a->b` and a function of type `b->c` and return a function of type `a->c`" (this is a simplified formulation. Please refer to the note below)

The second line the the definition of `f.g`. Its like defining functions in math. There you define a function `h` by saying what shall be result of `h(x)` for any given argument `x` (you can write `h(x)=x²` for example). You have read the line

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

as

```
(f . g)(x) := f(g(x))
```

which shall be read as: "The result of the function `f . g` for any given `x` shall be `f(g(x))`"

*Conclusion:* `->` is like the arrow in mathematics, which you might have seen in terms like `f : R -> R` and `=` is like `:=` (`f(x):=x²` means in mathematics, that `f(x)` is defined to be `x²`)

**Note:** The actual type of `(a -> b) -> (b->c) -> (a->c)` is (as mentioned by  @Ben Voigt): "function which takes a function of type a->b and returns a function which maps a function of type b->c onto ta function of type a->c". @jhegedus: Please let me note in the comments if you need explanation for it.

Comment: Third bullet looks wrong.  Composition is a function which takes a function of type `a->b` and returns a function which maps a function of type `b->c` onto ta function of type `a->c`.  Your description differs in that it assumes no currying.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are absolutely right. I just made a simppification which is easier to understand in the beginning. I will edit my answer...

Comment: Yours is undoubtedly easier to match up with the concept of composition.  But it's harder to match against the type notation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was the rewriting interpretation that I did not quite understand. The type annotation was quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the source code of (.), although it is close.  Here's the actual source:

```
-- | Function composition.
{-# INLINE (.) #-}
-- Make sure it has TWO args only on the left, so that it inlines
-- when applied to two functions, even if there is no final argument
(.)    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

(f . g) is a function.  The source uses a lambda form to be that function.  A lambda form must provide local bindings for each of its arguments.  In this case, there is only one argument, and it is locally bound to the name 'x'.  That's why 'x' (which is of type 'a') must be mentioned.

Since it is marked INLINE, it will effectively rewrite the code during the optimizer passes.  (IIRC, that's after desugaring (conversion to Core) and before conversion to STG.)

Lambdas are not sugar, they are fundamental.  let/where are sugar for lambdas.

Function definitions are *almost* sugar for lambdas, but the optimizer (in GHC as least) uses the arity in the definition to determine when/how to inline a function.  The type "(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c" can be thought of as any arity from 0 to 3, and can be defined with any of those arities.

Unnecessary parentheses can be used to strongly hint at the arity you want to use, although the slide does that backwards from the convention I've seen.  For example, adding parentheses around "a -> c" to get "(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)"; that type is generally thought of a binary function type.  The slides use that type, but then use a ternary definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,according to the accepted answer's author all definitions desugar to the same thing (see comments below accepted answer).

Comment: `let/where` can not be sugar for `lambda`. `lambda` bindings are not recursive, but `let` bindings in Haskell are. Plus, `let` bindings are pattern-matches, which would desugar to `case ... of`.

Comment: @WillNess No, you can do the desugaring by partitioning and then introducing calls to fix for any remaining mutually recursive partitions.  The haskell 2010 report goes does something similar, showing a equivalence between let -> case and then an equivalence between case -> lambdas.  Even then, let-generalization has to be handled separately, but mostly let is sugar for lambdas.

Comment: @WillNess http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-440003.12 has the (recursive) translation for let to case.  http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-610003.17.3 reduces cases.  Transition (a) and (d) are the first two transitions done when reducing case-expressions generated from let-expressions.

Comment: thanks!.. for one thing I was wrong about lambdas: `(x:xs)` in the lambda expression `\(x:xs)-> x` *is* a pattern... ...OK, so it does show that lambdas by themselves are insufficient, without the `fix`.

Comment: and `let` is shown being translated into `case` expression, not `lambda`: `let p = e1 in e0 = case e1 of ~p -> e0`. Also, 3.3 gives `\ p1 … pn -> e = \ x1 … xn -> case (x1, …, xn) of (p1, …, pn) -> e` so `case` does seem more fundamental than `let`.